# Build Jenkins and deploy on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, jenkins

Uninstalled all version of java from my machine and reinstalled the version 7 of Oracle:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: pt_BR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-61-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

why when using the foreman start the application works locally and when I do the build by Jenkins and implant in heroku the application launches java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError exception and Unsupported major.minor version 51.0? I'm using the wrong dependence? Where am I wrong?

I'm not getting solve this problem.

Any help will be very welcome!

Comment: What does `$ heroku run java -version` give you?

Comment: `$ heroku run java -version` 
Running `java -version` attached to terminal... up, run.4610
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true `java version "1.6.0_27"` OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.4) (Ubuntu build 1.6.0_27-b27) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: Because the version of Java is the sixth? I did not understand.

Comment: You must be using an old stack. make sure you have upgraded to cedar-14 per this guide https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-14-migration

Comment: Hello codefinger, solve the problem at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31998476/heroku-run-java-version-1-6-0-27?noredirect=1#comment51900905_31998476. Thank you very much for your help.